# Universal property for derived category of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, soft-question, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $D^{*}(X)$ be the unbounded (resp. unbounded, resp. bounded below/above, etc) derived category of coherent sheaves on $X$.

The work of [Robalo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3645) establishes a universal property for the motivic stable homotopy category of a scheme.

My question is simple: is it reasonable to think that the more classical derived categories may have similar universal properties?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what the universal property of the motivic stable homotopy category is, it will make the question more clear.